# Where is the electric field in a transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

to be honest, I'm rearranging my knowledge about electricity and the way of energy transfer from source to load on this answer is like a bulb just light for me (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/195121). 
But there is a case that I cannot understand well, that is how energy transfered from a primary coil to secondary coil in the transformer?
In the example of Resistor, it is clear that the Poynting vector goes into the resistor and make heat.
[image]
But what in case of a coil, or more specific, a transformer, how energy goes? All the explanation of transformer mentions that a changed magnetic field make an induced electrical potential in the coil. But if I look at the answer I mentioned above, I wonder if there is only magnetic element, then what is the direction of energy?
Should it point from a primary coil to secondary coil?
Please consider my draw, and let's assume that magnetic field directed by a magnet core.

[image]

---

P/s: can I say in the case of resistor, the Poynting vectors go into it, that means the resistor is consuming energy, and in case of inductor and capacitor, the poynting vectors go out, means the energy is conserved? If I'm not wrong, please show me how the conserved energy goes back to circuit?

Comment: The electric field in the primary coil, do you have problems with it? If no, then the same is valid for the secondary coil.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski yes indeed. In general, there is a voltage between two ends of coil, so there is a electric field inside it, parallel to the coil's centre and parallel to magnetic field goes through it. This is where I get confuse, because shouldn't magnetic and electric field perpendicular to each other?

Comment: The variable electric field in the secondary coil is "curly", if you like, due to Maxwell equations. It is perpendicular to the variable-in-time-but-uniform-along the coil core magnetic field. Generally a "near field" if not obliged to be always "perpendicular" like $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{H}=0$. It is far from the radiating source where fields are really perpendicular.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski that's how I thought too. And I think this curl electric lines is also presented at primary coil? So the Poynting vector point from primary to secondary coil and energy flow keep transfer between them. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: The energy only flows if the secondary coil makes part of a circuit with a current. Otherwise the enegy is transformed into the energy of magnetic field and returns into the primary coil (inductive "resistance" is not real, but a "reactive" one.

Comment: I don't know if this becomes obvious from any of what was said, but the electric field is between the windings. That's why we need to use insulated wire.

Answer (score 1):

For a transformer there is a primary coil and secondary coil, as I knew the Energy conservation law are the mutual energy theorem as the following,

$$
-\iiint_{V_{1}}\boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}(\omega)dV=\iiint_{V_{2}}\boldsymbol{E}_{1}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}^{*}(\omega)dV
$$

$\boldsymbol{J}_{1}$ is the current of primary coil, $\xi_{1}=[\boldsymbol{E}_{1},\boldsymbol{H}_{1}]^{T}$ is the electromagnetic field of the primary coil.

$\boldsymbol{J}_{2}$ is the current of secondary coil, $\xi_{2}=[\boldsymbol{E}_{2},\boldsymbol{H}_{2}]^{T}$ is the electromagnetic field of the secondary coil.

$$
-\iiint_{V_{1}}\boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}(\omega)dV$$

is the energy of $\boldsymbol{J}_{1}$ offer to the electric field of secondary coil $\boldsymbol{E}_{2}$

$$
\iiint_{V_{2}}\boldsymbol{E}_{1}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}^{*}(\omega)dV
$$
is the energy of the current $\boldsymbol{J}_{2}$ obtained from the electric field of the primary coil $\boldsymbol{E}_{1}$.

There is also a mutual energy flow theorem as the following,

$$
-\iiint_{V_{1}}\boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}(\omega)dV=(\xi_{1},\xi_{2})=\iiint_{V_{2}}\boldsymbol{E}_{1}(\omega)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}^{*}(\omega)dV
$$

$$
(\xi_{1},\xi_{2})=\iint_{\Gamma}(\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2}^{*}+\boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})\cdot\hat{n}d\Gamma
$$

$(\xi_{1},\xi_{2})$ is the mutual energy flow from the primary coil to the secondary coil. It is often thought that the energy flow is corresponding to the Poynting vector, that is wrong. The energy flow from the primary coil to the secondary coil is is the mutual energy flow! The mutual energy flow corresponding to a mixed Poynting vector
$ (\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2}^{*}+\boldsymbol{E}_{2}^{*}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1})$
instead of the Poynting vector
$ (\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1}^{*})$ and $(\boldsymbol{E}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2}^{*})$.

The Poynting vector
$\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{1}^{*}$ and $\boldsymbol{E}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{H}_{2}^{*}$
belong to the self-energy flow which cannot transfer energy.

The electromagnetic field of the primary coil $\xi_{1}$ is retarded wave. The electromagnetic field of the secondary coil $\xi_{2}$ is advanced wave. The mutual energy flow is a inner product of a retarded wave with an advanced wave. The advanced wave doesn't all accept as real objective existence in physics community and engineer community. Hence this energy conservation law and energy flow theorem still have the disputes.

The mutual energy theorem, is proposed by Shuang-ren Zhao in 1987 in Fourier domain. It is later found there is a time-domain reciprocity theorem proposed by Welch in 1960.

$$
-\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iiint_{V_{1}}\boldsymbol{E}_{2}(t)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{1}(t)dV=\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}dt\iiint_{V_{2}}\boldsymbol{E}_{1}(t)\cdot\boldsymbol{J}_{2}(t)dV
$$

The mutual energy theorem is the Fourier transform of the time-domain reciprocity theorem. The mutual energy flow theorem is introduced by Shuang-ren Zhao in 2017, 30 years later after he suggested the mutual energy theorem.

It is believe that the mutual energy flow is not just the energy flow from a primary coil to the secondary coil, but from an source to a sink. Here the source can be a primary coil, a transmitting antenna, an emitter. The sink can be a secondary coil, a receiving antenna, and an absorber. It is believe that the mutual energy flow from emitter to the absorber is the photon.

In quantum mechanics, there is absorber theory, introduced by Wheeler and Feynman, the absorber theory support the concept of advanced wave. The absorber theory believe that the current can sent out half retarded wave and half advanced wave. Based on the absorber theory Cramer introduced the transactional interpretation of the quantum mechanics. Cramer believe there is handshake process between the retarded wave and the advanced wave. The mutual energy flow theorem offer a details how the retarded wave and advanced wave worked together.